# BackgroundWorker Blocking Issue - Inconsistency between Integration Test and Real App

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm running into a weird situation.  I'm trying to use a list of BackgroundWorker instances, call RunWorkerAsync() on them, and then wait for all of them to complete before returning a response to the caller.  This is working well when I call the method from an NUnit integration test which exercises all of the code inside the workers.  However, when I execute from my web app, the very same code is constantly blocking the main thread and the RunWorkerCompleted callbacks never fire.  Why is this?  Here's my code (only using 1 BackgroundWorker here to illustrate, but I'm only using this when I have > 1 in actuality):

The main code that news up BackgroundWorkers and executes them in a blocking fashion:

```
// Build a list of BackgroundWorker instances representing the work needing to be done
var workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>
{
    GetContactsByFullNameAsync(lastName, firstName),
};

// Execute the work to be done (blocking during execution)
this.ExecuteAsyncWork(workers);

// Aggregate up the contacts and return the final result
return this.AggregateContacts(result);
```

Private function to new up a BackgroundWorker (but not execute it):

```
private BackgroundWorker GetContactsByFullNameAsync(string lastName, string firstName)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var result = new SuperSearchResultDTO();
        IList<Contact> contacts = _contactRepository.GetContactsByFullName(lastName, firstName);
        // Transform any resulting Contact instances to ContactDTO instances
        if (contacts != null && contacts.Count != 0)
            contacts.ToList().ForEach(c => result.Contacts.Add(ContactDTO.GetFromContact(c)));
        args.Result = result;
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
            // An error was thrown inside the repository, but since it was thrown in a separate thread, it 
            // won't stop the current thread from executing as per usual.  We need to log the exception with 
            // the results, and handle it later.  Throwing right here doesn't do anything.
            _asyncWork[source] = new SuperSearchResultDTO { Exception = e.Error };
        else if (e.Cancelled)
            _asyncWork[source] = new SuperSearchResultDTO { Exception = new Exception("GetSSOContactsByEmailAsync was cancelled") };
        else
            // Cast the results from type "object" to SuperSearchResultDTO
            _asyncWork[source] = (SuperSearchResultDTO)e.Result;
    };
    return worker;
}
```

Private method to execute all workers, block until completion and handle exceptions:

```
private void ExecuteAsyncWork(List<BackgroundWorker> workers)
{
    // Kick of the searches against the different data sources simultaneously
    workers.ForEach(x => x.RunWorkerAsync());

    // BLOCK the current thread until either all the async methods are complete 
    while (workers.Any(x => x.IsBusy))
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

    // Handle any exceptions
    var exception = _asyncWork.Where(x => x.Value != null && x.Value.Exception != null).Select(x => x.Value.Exception).FirstOrDefault();
    if (exception != null)
        throw exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're simply calling `Thread.Sleep` on the main thread, so it blocks. You need to use callbacks or events to solve this.